# CAN bus read on RPI3

Tags: pi-3, spi, communication, can-bus

I have 10 CAN IDs on the bus and would like to read all the 10 IDs every 0.1 seconds. I was able to write the code below but it shows me one message only.

```py
import can

bus = can.interface.Bus ("can0", bustype="socketcan")
reader = can.BufferedReader()
notifier = can.Notifier(bus, [reader])
msg = reader.get_message()
print(msg)
```

Is there a way to filter the CAN messages and send out buffered values for all the 10 IDs every 0.1 seconds?

Thanks,
Moe!